# Adding Authorization header to GET request

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, alexa-skills-kit, airtable

I'm building an alexa skill using the new SDK 2.0 and I'm now having trouble implementing a simple http get request. How would I add an authorization header to the getRemoteData url request? The code below isn't working.

I'm trying to call Airtable API to get some remote data

```
const UserReplyIntent_Handler =  {
canHandle(handlerInput) {
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    return request.type === 'IntentRequest' && request.intent.name === 'UserReplyIntent' ;
},
async handle(handlerInput) {
    const response = await httpGet();

    console.log(response);

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak("Okay. Here is what I got back." + response.records.fields.Indication)
            .reprompt("Would you like to learn more?")
            .getResponse();
},
};
```

```
function httpGet() {
return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {
    const headers = {
        Authorization: 'Bearer key12345678'
    };
    var options = {
        host: 'api.airtable.com',
        port: 443,
        path: '/v0/appYqfJ3Rt2F0sRGn/Database?filterByFormula=(DrugName=%27azatadine%27)',
        method: 'GET',
    };
    const request = https.request(options, {headers}, (response) => {
        response.setEncoding('utf8');
        let returnData = '';

        response.on('data', (chunk) => {
          returnData += chunk;
        });

        response.on('end', () => {
          resolve(JSON.parse(returnData));
        });

        response.on('error', (error) => {
          reject(error);
        });
      });
      request.end();   
}));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

header go into the options object, not as a separate parameter:

```
    var options = {
        host: 'api.airtable.com',
        port: 443,
        path: '/v0/appYqfJ3Rt2F0sRGn/Database?filterByFormula=(DrugName=%27azatadine%27)',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          Authorization: 'Bearer key12345678'
        }
    };
```

[https.request accepts the same options fields as http.reqest.](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback)
[http.request options object allows headers to be defined.](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback)

Comment: Ok fixed but my response is coming back as object object. Not sure how to stringify it into json or what I should do?